# Can I install a 4TB hard drive on my Gigabyte H57 motherboard?

Tags: windows-7

I have seen somewhere that there might be a 2.2 TB limitation on installed system's drive in Windows?

To be sure I do not buy something I cannot use, I wonder if my Gigabyte motherboard (GA-H57M-USB3 , rev. 1.0), with 4GB of RAM and an Intel Core i3 530 processor will accept a new 4TB hard drive as its system's drive (C-drive)?

I plan to re-install Windows 7 Pro - 64 bit.

Comment: Does your hardware support booting to GPT partitions?  This doesn't seem to be well researched.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 can boot from drives bigger than 2TB, but only for 64-bit Windows and only if using UEFI. Your motherboard does not seem to support UEFI, so this probably will not work the way you expect it to.

Reason for this is because old MBR partitioning scheme sector addressing is limited to only 2TB (= 512 bytes sector multiplied by maximum 32 bit number `2^32`, or 4 billion).

For drives bigger than 2TB, new partitioning scheme called GPT must be employed. GPT has 64-bit sector addressing, and supports drives to exabyte range and beyond.

Windows 7 (as well as most other modern operating systems) can understand both MBR and GPT. Unfortunately, your old BIOS doesn't. Most old BIOSes can recognize and boot only from MBR.

If you can switch your BIOS into UEFI mode, then it can perfectly understand what is GPT and how to boot from it.

In your case I would expect that you don't want to upgrade motherboard to newer one with UEFI support. Because of this, you can use old drive (smaller than 2TB) as boot drive, and new 4TB drive as data drive (`D:` or something).

Better yet, you can spend less than $200 and buy SSD disk to use as your boot and system drive (256 GB seems like sweet spot these days), and 4TB disk as data drive. This way, you will have best of both worlds - really fast system drive that can be booted from (using old trusty MBR), and roomy 4TB data drive to keep your big files (Windows will be able to use this 4TB drive without any trouble, even without UEFI).

Answer (score 1):

It is true, your disk must be GPT to create a partition greater than 2.2 TB.  Windows cannot even access space beyond 2.2 TB if it isn't a GPT disk, even via extended partitions, etc.  So, to utilize beyond 2.2TB, you must use GPT.

You cannot boot directly to a GPT partition without an UEFI motherboard.  However, it is *easy* to configure a USB stick as the primary boot device, which redirects the boot to a GPT disk.

I have a non-UEFI motherboard, and so I **cannot** boot directly to a GPT drive.  After following the steps in [this link](http://woshub.com/booting-windows-7-from-a-gpt-disk-using-bios-firmware-non-uefi/), my computer now boots to the USB stick, which redirects the boot to my 4TB GPT drive with my non-UEFI motherboard.

My basic steps were:

1. Partition the drive during a clean Windows 7 install to only use part of the drive.  The drive will be MBR, not GTP, so only the first 2.2TB will be accessible.  I only allocated 200GB to the C: (System) drive.
2. Follow [the instructions](http://woshub.com/booting-windows-7-from-a-gpt-disk-using-bios-firmware-non-uefi/) to convert the MBR drive to a GPT drive without losing any data.
3. Follow [the instructions](http://woshub.com/booting-windows-7-from-a-gpt-disk-using-bios-firmware-non-uefi/) to boot via the Win 7 Pro install disk, open a CMD window, and transfer the boot loader to the USB stick, and set the USB stick boot order above the HDD.

Without the USB stick, the computer will **not** boot.  So make sure nobody removes it.  You may want to label the USB stick "USB BOOT, DO NOT REMOVE".  Once in Windows, I used Disk Management to size my partition to whatever I needed, up to its full 4TB capacity, on a single drive+partition.

**<<< End of Summary >>>**

Full credit for [this solution](http://woshub.com/booting-windows-7-from-a-gpt-disk-using-bios-firmware-non-uefi/) goes to the original author - I take no credit!  However, just in case the link ever becomes unavailable, I will include the basics here (without screenshots and detailed explanation):

1. Install Windows to the new HDD.  It will only utilize some of the size, the rest will be inaccessible.
2. Boot to Windows, download [gptgen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptgen/) (utility that converts MBR to GPT without losing data)
3. From a CMD window:

```
   diskpart
   list disk
```

4. Find disk # to convert
5. From a CMD window, adjusting the ending # digit to the disk # from step 3:

```
   gptgen.exe -w \\.\\physicaldrive0
```

6. Insert the USB stick, and Windows 7 install CD, reboot
7. Boot to Windows 7 install disk, when prompted if you want to install, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open a CMD window.
8. From a CMD window, run the following commands, adjusting each per the output observed in prior steps:

```
   diskpart                          (runs tool)
   list disk                         (displays disks)
   select disk 0                     (select disk that matches the size of installed OS)
   list volume                       (find volumes on disk, note drive letter of OS volume)
   select disk 1                     (select disk that matches USB stick size)
   clean                             (clears contents of USB stick)
   create partition primary size=xxx (set xxx to MBs of USB stick)
   format
   select partition 1
   active
   list volume                       (list volumes on USB stick)
   select volume 3                   (select the new volume)
   assign letter=B                   (set the drive letter, I used `B`)
   list volume                       (verify drive letter)
   exit
   bcdboot c:\windows /l en-us /s b: (set the boot loader to redirect the boot to c:\windows from b:, adjust c: and b: as needed)
   bootsect /nt60 b: /mbr /force      (write boot code to USB stick)
```

9. Restart
10. Edit the BIOS and make sure boot order allows the computer to boot to the USB stick.
11. Restart.  Windows should now load.
12. Launch Disk Management, change the drive letter for the USB stick to `no assignment`, so it doesn't get used for something where someone might someday decide to remove the USB stick to use somewhere else.  I would label the USB stick `Win 7 Boot Loader` or something, and include `DO NOT REMOVE` on it.
13. Still in Disk Management, right-click the partitions on the multi-terabyte HDD and resize (or extend) the partitions as needed.